# Good practice web authentication with PBKDF2 and nonce in .NET

Tags: c#, security, authentication, pbkdf2, nonce

I'm building a web application and need to authenticate a user with a user password. I'm trying to build it to what would be considered a good security practice in 2021. As far as I've been able to gather from what I've read online, the following would be expected from sending the password from the client to the server over HTTPS (only).

[Edit: Context about the server]
On the server side I intend to store a salt per user and a hashed version of their password. On the wire I obviously shouldn't send the clear text password, but also, to prevent playbacks, I shouldn't send the hashed password value either. Hence the client side algorithm below.
[End edit]

1. User's password is hashed on the client [Edit: with the same salt as used server side].
2. Nonce is generated on the client [Edit: This should be server generated and given to the client, see comment]
3. The hashed password plus nonce is hashed on the client.
4. The nonce and final hash is sent from the client to the server over HTTPS.
5. Be sure to cleanup the password on the client (not in my code example).

Here is my experimental sample code:

```
public const int HASH_SIZE = 24; // size in bytes
public const int ITERATIONS = 100000; // number of pbkdf2 iterations
public const int NONCE_SIZE = 8; // size in bytes

public static string PasswordFlow(string userPassword, byte[] userSalt)
{
    // Hash the user password + user salt
    var hpwd = KeyDerivation.Pbkdf2(userPassword, userSalt, KeyDerivationPrf.HMACSHA512, ITERATIONS, HASH_SIZE);

    // Generate an 8 byte nonce using RNGCryptoServiceProvider
    RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
    byte[] nonce = new byte[NONCE_SIZE];
    rng.GetBytes(nonce);

    // Hash the hpwd byte[] converted to Base64 with the nonce byte array as salt
    var final = KeyDerivation.Pbkdf2(Convert.ToBase64String(hpwd), nonce, KeyDerivationPrf.HMACSHA512, ITERATIONS, HASH_SIZE);

    return Convert.ToBase64String(nonce)+"$"+ Convert.ToBase64String(final);
}
```

I would appreciate thoughts on the process above. Did I misunderstand it, screw it up or miss anything? I'm also trying to understand:

- Is it OK to use PBKDF2 twice?
- Is 100,000 iterations a reasonable size for PBKDF iterations?
- Is 24 bytes a reasonable hash size for PBKDF2?
- I presume 8 bytes a reasonable size for the nonce (64-bit number)?
- Is it a problem running PBKDF2 on the hash in base64 and nonce? (it expects a string input).

I'm not a security expert and I'm also a C# noob so please excuse any blunders.

Comment: Not a security expert, so take it with a grain of salt. Using the same encryption twice does not increase security and in some cases even decreases it. In your example, it seems that salt and nonce serve the same purpose. That is, a randomly generated number to increase entropy. One should be enough. In addition, if you send it through HTTPS that seems save enough.

Comment: You raise a good point I clearly didn't think about yet because I only sketched the client side code. So at the server i should only store a hashed value of the password with an constant salt. And i believe when i receive the nonce on the server i hash the stored hash with the nonce and if it equals the hash i received via https then it's a match.  That would imply I would need to send the salt to the client I suppose?!

Comment: Actually yeah, I didn't even think about how your server would handle the authentication when it receives some salt+hash. You might want to look into [SASL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Authentication_and_Security_Layer) which is used by many protocols for authentication. However, you might just want to send the password as plaintext since the entire point of HTTPS is to provide secure communication. See [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/110418)

Comment: Sending the pwd as plaintext or even as a hash that would match the server side stored hash isn't a good practice AFAIK. Because either can be intercepted and used in a playback attack. HTTPS isn't bullet proof and I believe sometimes HTTPS isn't truly P2P.

Comment: I've come to realize that it's easiest to generate the nonce at the server, give it to the client, and wait for the nonce calculated value to come back. If not, you'll need a list of historical nonce at the server to avoid playbacks - and over time that would be an unreasonable amount of data to manage of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PBKDF2 is designed to reduce brute-force attacks by increasing computational cost.
It is not intended to resolve problem of sending plaintext password - this should be done by other security mechanism - secure communication (i.e. TLS 1.3).

If secure communication is broken, then it does not matter if you have sent plaintext or hash of the password.

What you are referring as NONCE should be called SALT.

Basically, PBKFD2:

1. Takes any data you send (i.e. password)
2. Adds SALT
3. Applies PRF (Pseudo-Random Function) number of times
4. Returns n-bits of derived password

So, answering your questions:

1. It is ok to run PBKDF2 twice, however I would increase number of iterations, rather than run it twice
2. 100,000 is reasonable number of iterations
3. 24 bytes (192 bits) is reasonable hash size. Although you are using HMACSHA512 as PFR which produces hash of size 512 bits.
4. PBKDF2 standard allows 8 bytes SALT, however NIST recommends min. 16 bytes - I would increase SALT size
5. As mentioned earlier, you can run PBKDF2 on any string input. In most cases it would be password or passphrase

Comment: Thank you. The salt in my description is how the hash is stored on the server. The nonce is generated by the client and sent to the server together with the nonce hashed value. Thus, on the server side I can hash the stored hash with the nonce from the client. This achieves the goal of matching the password without sending any constant over the wire that could be used in a replay. AFAIU HTTPS can be inspected by e.g. your orgs firewall so i understand it's best to not send pwd in a replay friendly manner ;-)